# Spawning a light source in gazebo world

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to spawn light sources in a gazebo world through .urdf or .model files (similar to spawning solid models)? I was successful in doing so in electric but it is not possible in fuerte. Is there a way ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2166/spawning-a-light-source-in-gazebo-world/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/247/prasanna.kumar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Repeated question see [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2155/addiing-light-models-in-ros-fuerte/).

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1